# Playing the next video when the first one end with video tag as a playlist

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, loops, video

Hi I am not that good with javascript

I have videos and I want when the first video end to play the next video and so. Here is what I tried.

```
<div id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
      <%= video_tag "men-kicking-punching-fighting-during-combat-sport-karate-simulation_b8ltmb7kqx_1080__D.mp4", muted: 'muted',autoplay: :true ,style: 'display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;', class: "active"%>
      <%= video_tag "young-woman-dancing-on-the-stairs_hsua5f2_1080__D.mp4", muted: 'muted',autoplay: :true,style: 'display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;'%>
      <%= video_tag "videoblocks-happy-arabian-uae-sheikh-man-walks-in-middle-of-white-desert-and-enjoys-life-on-hot-summer-day_rbtvafcvw_1080__D.mp4", muted: 'muted',autoplay: :true,style: 'display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;' %>
    </div>
```

in java script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // get the active source and the next video source.
  // I set it so if there's no next, it loops to the first one
  var activevideo = document.querySelector("#myvideo video.active");
  var nextvideo = document.querySelector("#myvideo video.active + video_tag") || document.querySelector("#myvideo video:first-child");
  
  // deactivate current source, and activate next one
  activevideo.className = "";
  nextvideo.className = "active";
  
  // update the video source and play
  myvid.srcObject = nextvideo.srcObject;
  myvid.play();
});</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add another video when the video is end with video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092992/how-to-add-another-video-when-the-video-is-end-with-video-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To autoplay your videos 1 by1 when one had finished with **3 videos** remove the autoplay in order for your JS to work properly :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video') 
videos[0].play()

videos[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){

videos[1].play()

videos[1].addEventListener('ended',function(e){

videos[2].play()

videos[2].addEventListener('ended',function(e){

videos[0].play()

})

})

})

</script>
```

Comment: This will get you in a infinite loop playing your video 1-2-3-1-2-3...

Comment: It didn't work. no error just playing the first video then it stop

Comment: That's because you have more than 5 videos please remove unnecessary videos tags.. please check that. https://imgur.com/a/6ayRksd

Comment: I counted 6 and apparently you are using only 4 https://imgur.com/a/jyELLOe

Comment: Still the same https://protected-dawn-92091.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Here you can check its working just put the correct index of the videos... https://www.loom.com/share/a4d1aaedb60b419a83a224685078838c

Comment: Check the link top also check this link : https://www.loom.com/share/a4d1aaedb60b419a83a224685078838c

Comment: That's amazing :) I am sure you can do it but that's not what I want. I have 20 videos, I want for each column to be playing 3 videos with looping them just like tiktok.com

Comment: do the same process, but instead of playing only 1 video per set do it with 3 videos per column then.